# angularjs slim 404 not found for GET request

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I have browsed through the related posts here, but i cannot seem to get my application working.

I decided to use [generator-angular-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular-php)  to quickly setup an end-to-end application.

When i use grunt serve the application seem to work as intended, so i decided to put it, as is, on my apache server. I build it with grunt, and copied the files in the dist-folder to my
/var/www//public_html/

The structure is as follows:

- /public_html/

  - index.html
  - styles : css
  - views : view partials .html
  - scripts : angularjs controllers
  - api

    - index.php
    - .htaccess #1
    - vendor

      - autoload.php
      - slim

        - slim

          - index.php
          - .htaccess #2
          - Slim

            - slim php files eg Route.php
      - plenty of other dirs, eg. sebastian, doctrine...
    - tests
    - src : the example Api

The .htaccess #1 looks as follows:

```
 RewriteEngine On    
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The first index.php contains

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

try {

    // Initialize Composer autoloader
    if (!file_exists($autoload = __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
        throw new \Exception('Composer dependencies not installed. Run `make install --directory app/api`');
    }
    require_once $autoload;

    // Initialize Slim Framework
    if (!class_exists('\\Slim\\Slim')) {
        throw new \Exception(
            'Missing Slim from Composer dependencies.'
            . ' Ensure slim/slim is in composer.json and run `make update --directory app/api`'
        );
    }

    // Run application
    $app = new \Api\Application();
    $app->run();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    if (isset($app)) {
        $app->handleException($e);
    } else {
        http_response_code(500);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 500,
            'statusText' => 'Internal Server Error',
            'description' => $e->getMessage(),
        ));
    }
}
```

The .htaccess #2 looks as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA]
```

The second index.php contains php code to:

```
-Slim Framework and register its PSR-0 autoloader.
-Instantiate a Slim application
-Define the Slim application routes (get, post, put etc
```

In my site-enable file for my site i have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin hanto899@myphpportfolio.com
    ServerName myphpportfolio.com
    ServerAlias www.myphpportfolio.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myPhpPortfolio/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/myPhpPortfolio/public_html/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/myPhpPortfolio/public_html/access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/myPhpPortfolio/public_html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have enabled the rewrite-mod.

However, when i open up my site in a browser, i get an:

```
GET http://myphpportfolio.com/api/features 404 (Not Found)
```

with the response:

```
{"status":404,"statusText":"Not Found","description":"Resource \/features using GET method does not exist."}
```

I haven't altered the code in any way, and since it works durig grunt serve, I am guessing it should work without any alterering (?)
This is giving me more gray hairs, and I am out of ideas...what am I missing!

Comment: Did you come up with a solution to this?  I built an application using generator-angular-php and when I deploy to a server where I am admin, it works.  When I deploy to a server that is shared, it doesn't; so I'm curious what you came up with for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on the copied file and ownership.

When grunt builds and creates the final directory, it may change permissions and possibly ownership of the output files from /dist. chmod 755 -R the html directory with your website and possibly change owner(root?).

Also, those generators are sometimes configured to put out multiple builds builds....one for testing and one for live hosting.

For example, grunt test might output the images to a temp directory while grunt build outputs to /dist/images.